# Conditional Course Progression in Learndash

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook, learndash

Running out of ideas on how to conditionally set Course Progression in Learndash for certain users on certain topics.

Currently, Learndash can only support either Linear / Free form, and it dictates how the user learns. However, as an admin we can jump between topics and I cannot seem to find out the right function / filter on their documentation / source codes.

I tried:

```php
apply_filters( 'learndash_course_progression_enabled',  bool $setting,  int $course_id )
```

and also:

```php
learndash_can_user_bypass( int $user_id,  string $context = 'learndash_course_progression',  array $args = array() )
```

But all didn't work. Can someone shed some light?